# Random addresses getting printed undefinitely while booting kernel on armv7

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, linux-device-driver, interrupt, spinlock

Similar to ftrace, I have a function which prints addresses of all functions getting called while booting kernel on armv7 board. Addresses are printed properly before `setup_arch` function call in `start_kernel` function, but after that random addresses are getting printed. I think its the problem of spinlock since these addresses when mapped referred to functions like `_raw_spin_lock_irqsave` and `add_preempt_count`. It might not be spinlock problem.
Any suggestions on how to solve it?

Comment: It seems reasonable that spin_lock functions are called extensively after 'start_kernel'. Why do you say that these are random addresses?

Comment: @levengli I have my own function as I have stated in the question which I have added in `start_kernel` for testing purposes. It prints the addresses of kernel functions properly before `setup_arch` but after that random addresses gets printed which refers to locks. Is there any way to disable spinlocks?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, the question is how to disable spin_locks in order to clarify log files.

While disabling locks on a multicore system has an impact an may cause the system to err **to the extent of crashing** - it is possible to do so.

[include/linux/spinlock.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/spinlock.h) shows that spin_locks can be disabled by compiling the kernel with `CONFIG_SMP` and `CONFIG_DEBUG_SPINLOCK` undefined.

Comment: I think it might be due to some interrupts that are trying to acquire spinlock. Is there any way to check if interrupts are enabled when running my function.